# Finding closest item in list with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my list:

```
<ul>
    <a href=""><li>Link 1</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Link 2</li></a>
    <a class="dropdown" href=""><li>Link <div class="icon"></div></li></a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <a href=""><li>Link 1</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Link 2</li></a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <a class="dropdown2" href=""><li>Link <div class="icon"></div></li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Link 1</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Link 2</li></a>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

I want to find the closest "icon" class. How can I do this? $(this) refers to class "dropdown", "dropdown" etc.

```
$(this).find("li").closest(".icon");
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid as `li` elements should be direct children of `ul`, you need to move the `a` elements inside the `li`. Also, what is `this` referring to in your JS?

Comment: $(this).find("li").children(".icon");

Comment: I want the whole li to be a link, so that's why li elements are inside a.

Comment: Set a `display: block;` on the `a` inside of your `li` to make the whole `li` clickable.